# Shape of posterior distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, posterior

I have recently been reading and trying to understand the Bayesian paradigm and looking at various methods that people have been using to estimate the posterior distribution. Now, it seems that most of the intractability comes from the fact that the likelihood terms have a complex form or there are complex integrations to solve.

I was wondering what happens when the terms are from some well-defined distribution families. One problem I have been looking as an example has the following setup:

So, we want to estimate the parameters for the distribution of a random variable $w$ and we observe some data $d$ and we have a template $x$, so we want to estimate $p(w|d)$. Now assume that the data is observed IID and we have a Gaussian likelihood, so we can write the likelihood as:
$$
p(d|x,w,\phi) = \prod_i{\sqrt{\frac{\phi}{2\pi}}\exp^{-0.5(y_i-x_i)\phi(y_i-x_i)}}
$$
where $\phi$ is some global noise precision. Also, assume that the prior on $w$ is a multivariate zero mean normal prior $\it{N}(w; 0, \Sigma)$.

So, now the posterior distribution is as follows:

$$
p(w|d,x,\phi) =  \frac{p(d|x,w,\phi)p(w)}{\int p(d)}
$$

Now, my question is that since we have a Gaussian likelihood and Gaussian prior, is this posterior tractable and can we say something about how many modes it will have. Also, can someone help me understand intuitively why that may or may not be the case.

I would really appreciate any thoughts on this matter.

Comment: (1) what's a 'template'?  (2) are you sure you have the correct term in the front of your likelihood? Shouldn't it have a $\sqrt{\phi}$? (though this may be due to me simply misunderstanding with what's going on with $x$ in my first question).

Comment: The property of a prior-likelihood pairing having a tractable posterior is "conjugacy." This occurs most often in the Bayesian literature when using the exponential family of distributions. Looking around for "conjugate priors" will set you down on the right path.